# How Do I Safely Read an Encryption Key via a Haskell Command Line Program?

Tags: windows, haskell, encryption, cmd, command-line

I want to use the Clipboard and Cryptonite packages to create a simple command line password manager for MS Windows.

Somehow, I have to get the decryption keys from the user.  The easiest way would be to just use getLine.  Unfortunately, there are two problems with getLine:

1. Shoulder surfers may be able to see the user type in the decryption keys
2. I'm concerned the Microsoft Command Line interface (cmd.exe) will save those decryption keys where hackers can gain access to them

I thought about going GUI and using Gtk2Hs to get around these Command Line problems, but installing Gtk2Hs on an MS Windows system these days is quite a chore.  Also, GUI would probably add a lot of unnecessary complexity anyway.

For reasons I would rather not explain, I don't want to use ncurses or derivatives.

Does Haskell have a safe way I can get encryption keys from users via the Microsoft Windows Command Line?

NOTE: If Microsoft Windows command prompt is inherently insecure, that's not Haskell's problem.  I'm just asking if Haskell and MS Windows work nicely together so I can safely read encryption keys from via the command line.

Comment: What makes you think cmd.exe is not safe? Anyway, you could use an open source alternative like ConEmu + bash or something. (Still, I don't think there's a problem to fix here ?)

Comment: `getPassword` from the "haskeline" library could be useful to avoid unwanted echoing http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.7.5.0/docs/System-Console-Haskeline.html#v:getPassword

Comment: I will try getPassword from "haskeline" to get part of the decryption key and then retrieve the other part of the encryption key in a file.  Good to hear that getPassword works on *both* Windows *and* GNU/Linux

Comment: @chi - This isn't specifically an MS Windows problem, but historically, I think some command prompts like cmd.exe, BASH and even EMACS Shell mode have had histories. I'm concerned that if I do something wrong, the Encryption Key might wind up in some kind of shell history and somehow be extracted by a malicious process.